# How to enable tap in leftView/rightView when UITextField disabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITextField` where I added an image in `rightView`. I've added a gesture to this `rightView` and I would want to make it work when `UITextField` is disabled because this view is displayed only when not editing.

Here's an image sample of what I want to achieve:
[image: Webservice address]

- leftView is just an empty space;
- rightView has just the image.

Here's the code used to apply the appearance to the `UITextField` and apply the image to rightView:

```
- (void)applyAppearanceToTextField:(UITextField *)textField withRoundingCorner:(UIRectCorner)corner withIcon:(NSString *)icon {
    CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] initWithLayer:textField.layer.mask];
    UIBezierPath *shadow = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:textField.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
    shape.path = shadow.CGPath;
    textField.layer.mask = shape;

    // Apply space to the left as a padding
    [textField setLeftView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, textField.bounds.size.height)]];
    [textField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

    // Add the icon image to the right view
    CGFloat height = textField.bounds.size.height;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithIcon:icon backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] iconColor:[UIColor grayColor] andSize:CGSizeMake(height / 2, height / 2)];
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(5, 0, image.size.width, image.size.width)];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [textField setRightView:imageView];
    [textField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];
    [textField.rightView setExclusiveTouch:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleIconTap:)];
    [textField.rightView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)handleIconTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"handleIconTap");
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` I check if the field is filled so the field is disabled. How can I enable the tap in the leftView/rightView when the `UITextField` is disabled?

Comment: hi please put some code or image for better understanding ...

Comment: @ilesh edited the question with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue using the default UITextField component. I've created a boolean property to handle the value if field should be enabled which is set at `viewDidLoad`:

```
isEditEnabled = (self.myTextField.text != nil && self.myTextField.text.lenght > 0);
```

Then, I've implemented `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to return the value of `isEditEnabled` when this `UITextField` is clicked, implemented `textFieldDidBeginEditing` to set the backgroundColor of the textField to white and implemented `textFieldDidEndEditing` to set the backgroundColor to a dark gray and set the `isEditEnabled = NO` if myTextField is filled. The code is as follow:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.myTextField) {
        return isEditEnabled;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.text != nil && textField.text.length > 0) {
        if (textField == self.myTextField) {
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.80f alpha:1.0f];
            isEditEnabled = NO;
        }
    } else {
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        if (textField == self.url) {
            isEditEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
    activeField = nil;
}
```

This way I have the leftView and rightView always enabled for tap that was my goal.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this:

[image]

You can embed in a View your TextField and a UIButton (or UIImage if you need so) and set color and corner radius to your View